# FolderBrowserDialog topmost

Tags: c#, winforms

firstLogic

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
           DialogResult ret = STAShowDialog(dialog);
```

Second Logic

```
private DialogResult STAShowDialog(FolderBrowserDialog dialog)
{
    DialogState state = new DialogState();
    state.dialog = dialog;      
   System.Threading.Thread FolderBrowserThread = new System.Threading.Thread(state.ThreadProcShowDialog);
            FolderBrowserThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
            FolderBrowserThread.Start();
            FolderBrowserThread.Join();
            return state.result;
        }
```

last Logic

```
class DialogState
    {
        public DialogResult result;
        public FolderBrowserDialog dialog;

        public void ThreadProcShowDialog()
        {
            dialog.Description = "Select the folder where you want to save the WAV files.";
            result = dialog.ShowDialog(new Form(){TopMost = true,TopLevel = true}           );
        }
    }
```

FolderBrowserDialog Top most does not work.
The layer of the screen is the lowest layer.

No Errors !

I want to be called on the top layer

Comment: @Guy What should I do?

Comment: @Guy Not errors but  TopMost can not

Comment: your posted code is definetely not enough to reproduce your problem. There has to be more. How do you call `ThreadProcShowDialog` ? what do you before that, describe a little bit your context

Comment: @MongZhu sorce add

Comment: still not reproducible. When I try your code it shows top most.

Comment: what is your windows version?

Comment: @MongZhu windows 7

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162385/5174469) he is talking about a bug in Win 7 may be it helps

Comment: A dialog must *always* have an owner window.  The ShowDialog() overload is provided as a convenience, normally Winforms can find an owner by itself.  But sure, not here, that thread doesn't own any other window.   So at a minimum you'll have to annoy the user with a do-nothing form, at least he'll have a taskbar button to activate the window.   The *correct* way to draw the user's attention is with a NotifyIcon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BrowseForFolder-Dialog: center and make TopMost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769822/browseforfolder-dialog-center-and-make-topmost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void CreateMyTopMostForm()
{
   // Create lower form to display.
   Form bottomForm = new Form();
   // Display the lower form Maximized to demonstrate effect of TopMost property.
   bottomForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
   // Display the bottom form.
   bottomForm.Show();
   // Create the top most form.
   Form topMostForm = new Form();
   // Set the size of the form larger than the default size.
   topMostForm.Size = new Size(300,300);
   // Set the position of the top most form to center of screen.
   topMostForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   // Display the form as top most form.
   topMostForm.TopMost = true;
   topMostForm.Show();
}
```